# Hazelnut Tree In Front Yard, Squirrels!! Bad Idea?

Tags: trees, houseplants, tree-removal, fall-gardening, nut-trees

My husband and I just bought our first house with two big hazelnut trees in the front yard, it surely gave us a feeling of being close to the nature, but on the other hand, there are so many chestnut shells (opened and whole) dropping everywhere in my front yard. One thing that worries me is I constantly hear the hazelnut hitting my house (probably roof) and it's either because the chestnut is dropping in the fall season or the squirrels eat it and throws it from the tree. And quite often I do see squirrels on those trees.  Should I be concerned that it's going to be a problem to my house? I live in Ohio.

Thank you people!

Comment: Do you have chestnuts or hazelnuts? They're not the same tree, and hazelnuts are edible. To help with identification, are the nuts cream-colored/tan or a red-brown color? Hazelnuts have about a half-inch diameter while chestnuts are about an inch in diameter.  Personally, I wouldn't worry about the nuts or the squirrels, unless the trees are actually touching the house. Also, be aware that trees shading a house help keep the house's roof from aging quite as fast as if it were in full sun and also help keep any paint on the house from peeling.

Comment: You will certainly have problems if the squirrels get into your roof space, but being pelted with nuts won't damage anything. Be careful if they throw nuts at *you* when you are outside, though. They sometimes do that to defend their territory.

Comment: Many other trees produce seeds that you may find a nuisance such as: oak hickory,walnut, sweetgum ,sycamore, magnolia, many pines, and likely others.

Comment: I forgot two of the biggest; osage orange and apple , and depending on your location .citrus could be a problem.

Comment: @blacksmith I got hit in the head by a falling osage orange once; definitely not something I'd like to repeat. I'd like to add ginkgos to your list of nuisance seeds. In fact, I think I'd put the little vomit balls at the top of the list. :)